# Theoretical Computer Science Top User Swag

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Theoretical Computer Science t-shirt in your size
- Theoretical Computer Science die-cut, vinyl stickers
- Stack Exchange sharpie
- Stack Exchange pen
- Stack Exchange stickers

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: cstheory.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: cstheory.stackexchange.com sticker]

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- unfortunately we aren't able to gift this swag to everybody, but it will be available for sponsored events as needed)</sub>

Comment: Awesome ! although the all-time best gift from SE was the 32 GB USB stick that looks like an actual stick to beat something with :)

Comment: :) thanks .....

Comment: Sweet! Now I know what I'll wear for my first day at grad school. =)

Comment: Instead of having a gift can I buy a t-shirt? I'm willing to pay  20-30 usd for an XXL?

Comment: @JoshuaHerman I'm sorry, but we can't sell these at this point. We used to try and put custom site swag in our store, but the whole store thing worked out so poorly that [we had to shut it down](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store).

Comment: @AnnaLear Thanks, I am going to make myself a t-shirt using the branding logos.

Comment: Oh man, I'm the last person on the 2nd page, and actually tied with the top guy on the 3rd page. You guys are awesome for doing this. +1 to Raphael and +1 to Joshua - it would be nice to be able to order some of this stuff too.

Comment: Sweet________:)

Comment: Thanks! @Raphael: There is a long tradition of PhD students only wearing free t-shirts.

Comment: Thanks! .... :-)

Comment: I'm thinking maybe 4weeks for my designs to finish and put that on cafepress.

Comment: Should I worry that I haven't heard anything yet?

Comment: @JɛﬀE Shirts are being printed and should go out soon.

Comment: Should I worry that I haven't heard anything yet, even though I've actually seen someone wearing the shirt?

Comment: I received my package today, thanks!!!

Comment: @JɛﬀE Yikes, sorry about that. I looked through our records and we don't seem to have an address for you. Please email me (anna[at]stackexchange.com) with your address and t-shirt size ([sizing chart](http://www.apparelvideos.com/cs/CatalogBrowser?todo=mm&productId=4980)), and I'll get it out to you ASAP!

Comment: My package has arrived! Thanks!!! :-D

Comment: missed it by )( that much

Comment: hee, hee, **wheeee!!** finally snuck in while nobody was looking! now what, stackexchange? on initially seeing this, thought that maybe this program might be expanded over time but it appears quite the converse **=(**

Answer (score 1):

idea: it would be "way cool" for site promotion if this t-shirt could be purchased through a stackexchange store, and possibly other designs also.

also, msg to stackexchange admins, heres hoping that you revisit this type of promotion in the future. it would be really great & likely increase visibility of the site if it was repeated at some regular interval.

Comment: The SE store doesn't exist anymore because it wasn't practical for us to run it, sorry. :(

Comment: @anna thx for fast response wow makes me dizzy. maybe look into some kind of 3rd party fulfillment. "outsourcing"... hey c'mon swag was **your idea** not mine... and hey it was a _good one_ =)

Comment: [Fulfillment wasn't the problem.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137579/what-happened-to-the-stack-exchange-store). That said, we are still happy to provide swag for promotional events or site contests, etc.

Comment: @anna ok but on comments there, and the post, it insinuates that there would be routine swag gifts that would make up for the store closing. forgive me but it seems like stackexchange closed the store down _and_ discontinued much of a gifting/swag awards program. so hey! we get the worst of both worlds! yowza!

Comment: We try to interfere as little as possible, especially with the academic sites, so it's up to you guys as a community to organize an event. Many sites run some sort of anniversary celebration (CSTheory's anniversary is at the end of October), or a themed contest around a particular set of topics. I don't know how well either of those would fit with the community here, but if you want to organize something, start by kicking off a meta discussion and see if there's any interest from your fellow users.

Comment: @anna there is low interest here in site promotion among the members, have seen it a lot, hence my interest in this stackexchange-sponsored promotion & why its a great idea that stackexchange picked it up & took the initiative. it appears that management expects the community to promote it, but the community here is apparently not so interested in promotion any more after the initial push (even see it shoot down promotions). [maybe academic sites are marketing/promotion-avoidant as uncouth or something... if you have seen/heard otherwise, would certainly be interested in any case studies...]